# Creating / Deleting User in Ember with Array Controller

Tags: ember.js, crud

I am new to Ember and am trying to do a simple create / delete user. I am able to create a client, but can not delete them?

Client Controller:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    createClient: function(newName) {
        // Create the new Todo model
        var client = this.store.createRecord('client', {
            name: newName,
            avgMarkup: 2,
            quotes: 1
        });

        // Clear the "New client" text field
        this.set('newName', '');

        // Save the new model
        client.save();
    }
  }
});
```

I've then tried adding this:

```
    destroyRecord: function() {

        this.get('model').destroyRecord();

    }
```

And I have no luck. My view is this:

```
<ul id="client-list">
  <h6>Clients Name:</h6>
    {{input type="text" id="new-client" placeholder="Please enter client name"
    value=newName action="createClient"}}
  {{#each}}
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      <label>{{name}}</label>
      <button {{action "destroyRecord" }} class="destroy"></button>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Is this doable with an Array Controller?

Thanks

Comment: You need an `itemController` for this to work. Otherwise, which item are you deleting?

Comment: Thanks Kalman. I do not currently have an itemController. What would this house? (I only have the clientController). The item I am hoping to delete is the user. So when a user is created (which I am able to do), an 'x' appears next to their name and clicking that would delete them. However, I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the respective user just pass it to your `destroyRecord` action:

In your template pass `this`which correspond to the current user being iterated:

```
<button {{action "destroyRecord" this}} class="destroy">Destroy</button>
```

And then when someone click in destroy button, `model` will be the current user:

```
destroyRecord: function(model) {
    model.destroyRecord();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcio for the info! I just tried that and am now getting 'undefined is not a function'? I looked and it appears destroyRecord() should be valid?

Comment: Never mind, it was a syntax error. This worked! Thanks so much.